# How can I run two instances of Civ 5 on the same computer (ports conflict when playing LAN)?

Tags: civilization-5

I have two copies of civ 5, and I am using a program called [SoftXPand](http://www.miniframe.com/) to have a multiseat setup.  Both copies of civ 5 run fine, but when I try to connect to the other in the Local Network it says "error connecting to multiplayer session" .  I am able to connect to another computer in the network though.  So I assume this is a problem with a port conflict.  Does anyone have any way I can get this to work?

Comment: If you mean port forwarding, this doesn't apply to your Local Network (LAN).

Comment: No I do not.  I mean two copies of Civ 5 are trying to bind to the same port on the same computer.  Though I have not had this problem for other games, it seems just civ does this.

Comment: I don't think you can bind two applications to the same port.  That...counteracts the whole purpose of having dedicated channels for applications.  Maybe you can change the port one instance uses?

Comment: Yeah, @fbueckert is right. Two applications can *not* bind to the same port, ever. Changing the instance of one instance seems to be the only possible way.

Comment: Have you tried [virtualization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtualization)?

Answer (score 1):

You might have already figured this out, but I have an explanation.

If you only have one wireless (or Ethernet) card in your computer, you will only have ONE IP address.

Both instances are trying to use the same address, and this is leading to your "kicking" issue - they are trying to override one-another.

You could purchase a second card (let me know how that works, I'm a bit curious), or changing the port one of your instances runs out of.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This shouldn't be necessary, for the same reason that you can run different application on the same machine (i.e. with the same IP address). As long as the OP can ensure the two instances use a different port number, the IP address won't matter.

Comment: Maybe a WIFI-Stick would be cheaper than a second network-card.

Comment: FYI: You can assign two IP addresses to the same network card in the ipv4 settings panel.